# Ionic Security SDK version

Tags: ionicsecurity

is there a way for a dev or QA person to list/verify the Ionic SDK version installed? I’ve seen the PKG-INFO file on my local system (Mac with the Python 1.5.0+7 SDK). However, I wanted to see if there was an elegant way to do this similar to::

python -c ‘import ionicsdk; print(“hello”)’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question. In the Python SDK, as of version 1.5, the version number is available in a constant `ionicsdk._private.IONIC_SDK_VERSION`.

For example, from the command line like you were asking about, it would be used such as:

```
$ python -c ‘import ionicsdk; print(ionicsdk._private.IONIC_SDK_VERSION)’
1.5.0+546
```

(There may be additional ways to access it available in the future.)